# Use Windows XP sounds in OS X?

Tags: macos

I have a zip file of all Windows XP sounds. Is there a way I can replace the standard OS X sounds with these?

Comment: What explicitly do you mean by "_a way I can replace_", do you mean physically replace the files at `/System/Library/Sounds` or just make available to System Preferences > Sound? If you just want the _.wav_ files to show under System Preferences > Sound, then simply copy them to `$HOME/Library/Sounds` and the'll be available in System Preferences > Sound. **No conversion to another format is required or necessary.**

Comment: But why? I mean... WHY?

Answer (score 3):

You technically can't replace the sound files as they are protected by SIP (well... you *could* by disabling SIP, but that's another discussion altogether), but you can add sound files to your own personal library.  This is much easier to do.

There's basically two steps to this:

1. Convert your WAV file to AIFF.
2. Copy the file to `~/Library/Sounds` (Note that this is located in your user directory and not the *SIP protected* `/System/Library` directory).

The easiest way to do this is to use [FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org)<sup>1</sup>  Just issue the command `ffmpeg -i <path><name of file>.wav ~/Library/Sounds/<name of file>.aiff` and it will do both steps in one shot.

The nice thing about using FFmpeg is that you don't have to manually open each file in QuickTime as you can do it right from Terminal.  This also means you can write a quick batch file to do all your sounds if you like.

Once you do that, it should show up in Sound Preferences as a "Custom" sound (I created an "Ask Different Sound" specifically for this example).  *Be sure to completely close out of System Preferences (if open) before going into "Sound" so that it can load up the new files.*

[image]

---

<sup>1</sup>  FFmpeg is open source, free software that converts almost any audio/video file from one format to another. Simply download the binary and make sure it can be found in your path.  I just copied it to `/usr/local/bin` so I didn't have to modify my path at all.

Comment: One does not need to convert a WAV file to another format in order to use it under OS X. Simply add the _.wav_ files to `$HOME/Library/Sounds` and the'll be available in System Preferences > Sound.